# Java OO design: a Person can be either Singer, Pianist or both

Tags: java, oop, multiple-inheritance

A Person can either be a Pianist, which has a .play() method, either a Singer,  which has a .sing() method, either both a Pianist and a Singer, in the latter case he would be able to .sing() and also to .play()

What would be a possible design for this situation?

Comment: A person can *perform* as Singer or Pianist (or both!).

Comment: @Tyler Treat no! I'm too old for school:-) I found this situation in JS prototypal OO, and want to know the Java alternative.

Comment: @devaoured elysium could you elaborate? I think you have something great in mind:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like homework to me.

I would suggest you want to use [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and capability objects. In this case, make the instruments the performer knows how to play be capabilities.

You would have something like this:

```
class Performer extends Person {
     List<Capability> capabilities;
}

// Perhaps call it 'Skills'
interface Capability {
     public void play();
}

class Pianist implements Capability {
     public void play() {
         // ....
     }
}

class Singer implements Capability {
     public void play() {
         sing();
     }

     public void sing() {
         // ....
     }
}
```

Comment: I am already too old for school unfortunately... This is the best answer I've read so far:-)

Comment: This is probably the most _generic_ solution. However, some of the other solutions may be more appropriate to your use case, based on what you need to do.

Answer (score 7):

`Pianist` and `Singer` will have to be interfaces, with those respective methods.

Then you might have a class for a specific person who is both a `Pianist` and a `Singer`:

```
class DoublyTalentedPerson implements Pianist, Singer {
  public void play() {...}
  public void sing() {...}
}
```

Comment: if we have something like: Person implements Singer, Pianist
then Person has to implement sing() and play() as well. In that case a Person will always be both. Maybe I misunderstood your solution.

Comment: Updated to clarify.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes but you will duplicate code by implementing play in DoublyTalentedPerson, and play in Pianist, the same goes for sing().
Also it is not very extensible

Comment: That's _basically_ not avoidable in Java.  There are a few workarounds -- for example, you can have `DoublyTalentedPerson` extend some `BasePianist` object, so you only have to reimplement one method.  But that was the choice Java made when it forbade multiple inheritance except for interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is probably what you're looking for...

```
public interface Peformer {
    //...
}

public interface Pianist extends Performer {
    void play();
}

public interface Singer extends Performer {
    void sing();
}

public class SingerImpl implements Singer {
    public void sing() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class PianistImpl implements Pianist {
    public void play() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class PianistSingerImpl implements Pianist, Singer {
    public void play() {
        // ...
    }

    public void sing() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but if I want to modify play(), I have to modify it in PianistImpl AND PianistSingerImpl, because there is duplicated code. (and worse, if I decide to extend my application and add a guitarist, it becomes quickly a mess)

Comment: @Matthew: so you're saying all pianists play the same way and all singers sing the same way?

Comment: If a PianistSinger sings in a different way than a Singer, that's ok. But I have never specified that. Anyway, sounds like JBCP has a nice solution which avoids that duplicated code situation.

Comment: If that's the case, it sounds like an abstract class might be more appropriate to contain common code.

Comment: but don't forget that there is no multiple inheritance, thus that abstract class will have to have all the methods play() and sing(), and will be inherited by the Impl classes, thus the SingerImpl will inherit .sing() but will need to override .play() to throw an UnsupportedActionException for example. Or did you have in mind something more simple?

Answer (score 0):

Person can be very good singer and can play piano along with the singing. But his main professional is Singing. So in this case, we can derive Person class from Singer and implement Piano interface. This holds true in the other way also (Person is good piano player and he usually sing the song as he plays the piano). In this way Singer can play multiple instruments like Guitar, Piano, Drum etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Singer {
  void sing();  
}

interface Pianist {
  void play();
}

class SingerImpl implements Singer {
  public void sing() {}
}

class PianistImpl implements Pianist {
  public void play() {}
}

class SingerPianist implements Singer, Pianist {
  public void sing() {}
  public void play() {}
}
```

A person that is just a singer derives from `SingerImpl`. A person that just plays piano derives from `PianistImpl`, and a person that does both derives from `SingerPianist`.

Comment: As I said to Tyler Treat which proposes the same solution: "if I want to modify play(), I have to modify it in PianistImpl AND PianistSingerImpl, because there is duplicated code. (and worse, if I decide to extend my application and add a guitarist, it becomes quickly a mess)"

Comment: Yeah, if you're adding more capabilities, then JBCP's answer is the way to go.

Comment: even if I don't add a capability, there is still duplicated code here in PianistImpl and SingerPianist. if a programmer changes method play in PianistImpl and forgets about SingerPianist, it will be buggy. So in either cases I think JBCP's solution is the way to go.